# MySQL cluster data node restarts when its twin fails

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

Configuration:

- Server #1: 1 mgm node, 1 data node, 1 sql node
- Server #2: 1 mgm node, 1 data node, 1 sql node

Specification:

- MySQL Cluster 7.3.6 x86_64
- Debian 7.6 x86_64

It's been deployed by using MySQL Cluster Auto-Installer. Every thing works just fine.
But, when I shutdown one node, the data node on the other server gets restarted. NDB_MGM shows that it is "starting". And it takes long to exit "starting" state.
As I tested it won't happen when there are four nodes.
Doe anyone know what the reason of this restarting is?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What value have you configured for NoOfReplicas ?

Comment: I used auto-installer, with "simple testing" and "medium" values for "Application area" and "Write load" parameters. I guess it's 2, because after I restart one node, I'm still able to retrieve data from the other. Of course after restarting.